# How to remove a character from the string and change data if need it?

Tags: c++, stl

I have possible inputs 1M  2M .. 11M and  1Y (M and Y stand for months ) and I want to output "somestring1 somestring2.... and somestring12" note M and Y are removed and  the last string is changed to 12

```
    Example: input "11M" "hello" output: hello11
             input "1Y" "hello" output: hello1



char * (const char * date, const char * somestr)
{
    // just need to output final string no need to change the original string
    cout<< finalStr<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Question not too clear..
Can you explain a bit more

Comment: Give an example of input and expected output.

Comment: OK,fixed the description. Thanks

Comment: In this case, post the code and lets see whats the issue...

Comment: I need help coming up with the code. no too familiar with cpp.

Comment: The caller should provide the input buffer:
`char* fn(char* input, const char* date, const char* someString)
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this homework? If not, here's what i'd suggest. (i ask about homework because you may have restrictions, not because we're not here to help)

1) do a find on 'M' in your string (using `find`), insert a '\0' at that position if one is found (btw i'm assuming you have well formatted input)

2) do a find on 'Y'. if one is found, insert a '\0' at that position. then do an atoi() or stringstream conversion on your string to convert to number. multiply by 12.

3) concatenate your string representation of part 1 or part 2 to your somestr

4) output.

This can probably be done in < 10 lines if i could be bothered.
the a.find('M') part and its checks can be conditional operator, then the conversion/concatenation in two or three lines at most.

Answer (score 2):

The second string is getting output as a whole itself. So no change in its output.
The second string would be output as long as `M` or `Y` are encountered. As `Stack Overflow` discourages providing exact source codes, so I can give you some portion of it. There is a condition to be placed which is up to you to figure out.(The second answer gives that as well)
Code would be somewhat like this.

```
//Code for first string. Just for output.
for (auto i = 0 ; date[i] != '\0' ; ++i)
{
  // A condition comes here.
   cout << date[i] ;
}
```

And note that this is considering you just output the string. Otherwise you can create another string and add up the two or concatenate the existing ones.